# How do I hide content based on user role?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

In my auth service I have an observable `user` that get populated from a firebase backend.

I also have a method that takes the user object and returns a boolean if the user has the role that is passed in.

In my template I have some elements that I only want to show when the logged in user has the `admin` role for instance listed as one of their roles.  I'd need it to function as such that I could eventually use is('contributor'), etc. and still get back a boolean.

Right now when I try and test it the browser hangs and eventually crashes. How can I set things up so that the div is hidden until the data resolves if and when the role of the user matches the requirement?

```
// authService

  this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
      } else {
        return of(null)
      }
    })
  )

is(role){
    let p = Promise

    this.user.toPromise().then(resolvedUserData=>{
    (_.has(role, resolvedUserData.roles)) ? p.resolve() : p.reject(); 
   })

   return p;
  }


 //template

 <div *ngIf="authService.is('admin') | async">admin content here</div>
```

Comment: Check out how this is handled in jhipster generated applications, they use a has-authority directive, has always done the trick for me when hiding/showing elements based on roles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849498/has-authority-not-working-on-a-button

Comment: you can add a variable within the is(role) function and set it to false, set it to to true once the promise is resolved. In your div, check for that variable and only show that once it's true && autoService.si('admin') is true. I believe it doesn't check for the second statement if the first statement is false, so the second statement won't crash your page.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is returning a promise and async pipe needs an observable.

// AuthService

```
isAdmin = false;

this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
switchMap(user => {

  if( check if use is admin){
      this.isAdmin = true;
  }
})
```

)

// Template

```
 <div *ngIf="authService.isAdmin">admin content here</div>
```

Now I am not sure this the best approach from a security stand point. I would have some other sort of validation or token. But this approach answers what you gave. Cheers.

Comment: this changes the functionality which isn't quite what I need.  I added more clarification to question.

Comment: Why convert the observable to a promise then use the async pipe? Just use the observable then.